# Missing { after argument list

Tags: jquery

This is missing a semi colon or curly bracket or something and I can't find out where or how.

Any suggestions on how to debug this sort of issue would help. I added one on the line firebug told me and it still didn't work nor make sense.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#go').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#newsletter').serialize(),
                    url: $('#newsletter').attr('action'),
                    success: function()
                    {
                    $('#thankYou').show(1000,setTimeout(

                    function(){
                    $('#thankYou').hide()
                    })

                    ,3000);


                    };
                });
                 return false;
            });

        });
```

it is still showing a syntax error with this

```
function()
                    {
                    $('#thankYou').show(1000,setTimeout(

                    function(){
                    $('#thankYou').hide()
                    })

                    ,3000);


                    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the three semicolons above the final one are erroneous, but I'm not sure.

Comment: you sure there is not another code inside ? or error console plugin on some browser is useful plugin. you might try it.

Comment: I use [JSLint](http://jslint.com/). It will tell you your errors and where they occur. It's a little intense, but you can change the settings to be more liberal if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like 3 problems:

1. The extra semicolon.
2. `show()` syntax.
3. `setTimeout()` syntax.

This should work; [**See it in action at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wsyAp/2/). :

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $('#go').click ( function () {
        $.ajax ( {
            type:       'POST',
            data:       $('#newsletter').serialize (),
            url:        $('#newsletter').attr ('action'),
            success:    function () {
                            $('#thankYou').show (
                                1000, 
                                function () {
                                    setTimeout ( function() { $('#thankYou').hide(); }, 3000);
                                }
                            );
                        }
        } );
        return false;
    } );
} )
```

**PS:** For just showing and hiding, jQuery provides:

```
success:    function () {
                $('#thankYou').show (400).delay (2500). hide (400);
            }
```

("We don't need no stinking setTimeout.")

Comment: thanks this worked it just didnt work when i pasted it into firebug. then executed.

Comment: Glad we got it figured out in the end.

Answer (score 6):

You should do more nesting on those functions, it may help you figure it out in the future. Here is the code more indented:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#go').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#newsletter').serialize(),
            url: $('#newsletter').attr('action'),
            success: function() {
                $('#thankYou').show(1000, setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#thankYou').hide();
                }), 3000);
            };
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The problem is the ';' after the success function declaration.

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
                    ,3000);


                }; //<-- that should not have a semicolon
```

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion. You could actually have a comma there if you like, which you would need if you're going to add other attributes to $.ajax

Comment: Yeah, a comma would be the best choice there.

Comment: Except that a trailing comma will break IE8 and lower.